# Get and compare first item from drop down menu with an string in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a dropdown menu with 2 options(option1 and option2).I want to get the NAME of the first option and compare with a string.
I tried something like this but not work for me:

```
The drop down menu has two items:
            -first(default) is "simplex"
            -second is "duplex"
```

The HTML drop down is:

```
    <div class="fieldHelp " id="fieldHelp8352">
<script></script>
<select id="8352" class="lazy-droplist" aria-labelledby="8351" name="pMode:value" style="display: none;">

<option selected value="0">simplex</option>

<option value="1">duplex</option>
</select>
<label id="extendClickArea_8352" style="height:40px; width:100%; position: relative;" class="lazy-droplist">
<span class="ui-selectmenu-button lazy-droplist" tabindex="0" id="8352-button" role="combobox" aria-expanded="false" aria-  autocomplete="list" aria-owns="8352-menu" aria-haspopup="true" style="width: 100%;" aria-activedescendant="ui-id-1003" aria-    labelledby="ui-id-1003" aria-disabled="false" data-modalfocus="">
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span>
<span class="ui-selectmenu-text">simplex</span>
</span>
</label>
<div id="bs-help-modal-sm-8352" style="display: none;" class="bs-help-modal-sm-8352 ui-draggable" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"   aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-header ui-draggable-handle">
<button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" onclick="closeHelpPopup(event, $('#bs-help-modal-sm-8352'));">
<span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
.....
.....
</div>
<script>
$('#bs-help-modal-sm-8352').draggable({ handle: '.modal-header' });
</script>
</div>
```

Noticed that the  code is somehow grayout,inactive but when I tried to extract test "simplex" ,not said that the menu is hidden or something...

Java code is:

```
            Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("simplex")));
            WebElement option = select.getFirstSelectedOption();
            String defaultItem = option.getText();
            System.out.println(defaultItem);->this variable is empty :(

            if (defaultItem == "simplex") {
                System.out.println("Is Simplex");
            } else {

                System.out.println("Is Duplex");
```

Where I do something wrong because defaultItem is empty...
Thks

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.
The solution was:

```
String Text = driver.findElement(By.id("the_direct_path_to_this_span_<span class="ui-selectmenu-text">simplex</span>")).getText();
if(text.equals("Simplex"))
{
System.out.println("Is Simplex");
} else {

System.out.println("Is NOT Simplex");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I cant see name attribute with "simplex" anywhere in the code provided by you. Also, a problem I can see in HTML code is it does not have any value for a selected attribute that's why you getting the empty value:

```
<option selected="" value="0">simplex</option>
```

Try below method:

```
Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("8352")));
List<WebElement> options =  select.getOptions();
int optionssize=    options.size();
for(int i=0;i<optionssize;i++)
{
  if(options.get(i).getText().equals("Simplex"))
  {
    System.out.println("Is Simplex available at"+i);
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Then you can try : 
//div[@class='fieldHelp']/select

Comment: Thank you for the help but not work.Is working with (By.xpath(".//*[@class='ui-selectmenu-text']")) but java give me this error " element should have been select but was span.." .I need just to extract de text from first option displayed in the drop down...

Comment: //div[contains(@id,'fieldHelp')]//select[@class='lazy-droplist'] then try this xpath to get select element

Comment: The last xpath is OK in the way of error but the condition "if(options.get(i).getText().equals("simplex"))" (your method) or "if (defaultItem == "simplex")"(my method) is never applied,somehow the selected item "simplex" or "duplex" is not extracted correctly like a text(string) in order to compare...sorry I dont't want to disturb if you are busy ...I am beginner in java and webdriver

Comment: Not an issue... 
What you getting while running the script in this place :
System.out.println("Is Simplex available at"+i);
Try to debug and if you get the error show it. So that i can get some idea whats happening

Comment: I figure out whats going on:"System.out.println("Is Simplex available at"+i);"

Comment: I figure out whats going on:"System.out.println("Is Simplex available at"+i);" give me blank ,nothing...this is the reason that "if(options.get(i).getText().equals("simplex"))" is never applied.Like I said above "somehow the selected item "simplex" or "duplex" is not extracted correctly like a text(string) in order to compare".